# Make grid with multi emoticons load faster?

Tags: android

Currently i have been working in android project chat applications and i have to create a view display a grid of emoticons icons. I have create grid emoticons load like line app picture below. But the problem is my grid load very slow and it very lag to scroll. Can anyone suggest me how to make it better in load performance and scrolls.
[image]

Comment: can you post your code of gridView, you may not be using holder pattern and async image loading

Comment: You should post the code that generates that grid so we can know how to best help you.

Comment: Also you can try to avoid the images being scaled at runtime.